# Element disappears when my page is done loading

Tags: html, tumblr

So I just installed a new theme on my Tumblr page and I tried to add my drop-down hover box, It works, I can see the boxes while my page is loading but when it's done, It disappears..

I'm okay with html and css but I don't know how to fix this, can someone explain what I should do?

this is my page, the boxes should be on the right http://daisyscars.tumblr.com/

Comment: With infinite scroll, technically it's never done loading. Anyway, what drop-down hover box do you mean? If you want people to see the source of your page, don't make it hard to see it, OK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is it

```
<div id="lol">
<!-- Content here...--> 
</div>
```

Add the `top` property to `#lol` and set its value to `40px` (You can change it, but I think it's fine)

```
#lol {
/* Just add the following and don't remove the other properties */
top: 40px;
}
```

You can find it on the line: 2101 of your HTML

Answer (score -1):

This also happened to me and the solution is simple.
All you have to do is Go to Chrome Settings and go to Advanced select Reset Settings and click on Restore settings to their original defaults and click on Reset Settings. After that search anything(like movies) and it will be all fine!!

Note: If you have any extensions they will be DISABLED. In order to enable them go to Chrome Settings click on Extension and ENABLE the extension you want!!

Thats it !! Hope it helps

```
                                                        By: Mayank Pavuskar
                                                        From: Goa, India
```